# Aumentar quantidade de inputs do form enviados no post php

Tags: php, post

trabalho com um sistema livre e estou com um problema em uma rotina em que o sistema cria uma tabela de itens, e para cada campo de valor de cada item é criado um input, onde o name recebe o código do item, porém nesse caso, existem mais de 400 itens, e ao clicar em incluir, só chega do outro lado no POST 327 itens, vocês tem uma ideia de como posso aumentar a quantidade de campos enviados via POST pelo form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abra o php.ini e altere o valor de `max_input_vars` para um número adequado essa configuração define o número de inputs enviados em uma requisição, talvez seja necessário mudar o valor de `post_max_size` que é o tamanho(mb/gb) de informação enviada, após a modificação reinicie o apache.

Exemplo:

```
max_input_vars = 600
post_max_size = 16mb
```

Para visualizar os valores correntes dessas diretivas faça:

```
<?php
   echo ini_get('max_input_vars') .'<br>';
   echo ini_get('post_max_size');
```

Comment: aumentando o max_input_vars resolveu o problema. Muito obrigado amigo!

Comment: @RobsondeJesus pode marcar a resposta com a setinha verde para indicar que o problema foi resolvido :)

Comment: coloquei max_input_vars = 1200
post_max_size = 254mb ai não aparece nenhum resultado